# Accessing "self" in save method of class-based model

Tags: python, django

I have two models that look like this:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        a = ModelTwo.objects.get(pk=arbitrary_pk)
        a.somefield.add(self) # I am worried about this line here
        super(ModelOne,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    somefield = models.ManyToManyField(ModelOne)
```

The line where I am adding `self` to `a.somefield` is the line I am worried about. How can I do this without error? Currently, I am getting:

`ValueError: Cannot add "<ModelOne>": the value for field "modelone" is None`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try post_save signal? Seems like you cant add it before actually saving it. Or try doing it after super.

Comment: Can you please post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because when you call .add() you have yet to save your model. That means that the model may not have been created (so it doesn't have an ID yet).

Basically you're telling Django to update the Foreign Key with something that doesn't exist yet (NULL), which will error out. You need to make sure the model has been created before you can set the foreign key.

try moving the a.somefield.add(self) to AFTER the super() call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save many to may field before calling actual save method, you modify code like,

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(ModelOne,self).save(*args,**kwargs) # Here your self has been saved
    a = ModelTwo.objects.get(pk=arbitrary_pk)
    a.somefield.add(self) # Now your self can be add as ManyToMany as it is already saved in db
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the instance to the many to many field after calling the save method.

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ModelOne,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        a = ModelTwo.objects.get(pk=arbitrary_pk)
        a.somefield.add(self) #add self to the object manytomany.
        a.save() #save the object.

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    somefield = models.ManyToManyField(ModelOne)
```

You need to save the self object first. The many to many relation needs to have the related object saved in the database first, inorder to define the relationship. Then, define the relationship using `a.somefield.add(self)`. Then, save the `a` object. Otherwise, the relation won't be committed in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up utilizing post_save to get this to work.